# How do I create a variable accessible by any function in a class in python?

Tags: python

I have some code inside of a class. I want my load variable to be accessible by any function in my class, so I put my variable directly in the class. I get the error: NameError: name 'load' is not defined.

```
load = Image.open('obama.jpg')
def showImg(self):
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

    img = Label(self, image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=0,y=0)

def hideImg(self):
    load.close()
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the class definition in which the code you posted lives.  If possible, put an example of the invocation of the method and the error message as printed in the terminal.  — That said, why on Earth the method is defined  `def hideImg(self):`, I mean, does `self` serve any purpose?

Comment: @gboffi The class for this code is now long gone; I am at risk of being banned from asking more questions; what can I do to reverse this risk in light of me not having the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access it by `self.<property_name>` so in this case `self.load`

Answer (score -2):

```
global load 
load = Image.open('obama.jpg')
def showImg(self):
    global load
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

    img = Label(self, image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=0,y=0)

def hideImg(self):
    global load
    load.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.